# Reset user vote every 24 hours - Swift

Tags: swift, time

In my app, every 24 hours a user can vote on one particular racing course that they like. However every 24 hours after they voted I would like them to be able to vote again.

I understand the basics of NSTimer - Would I be looking to create a log of when they closed the app and a log of when they opened it again and comapre the times and calculate if it has been 24 hours?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: I don't know about swift, but logs are not meant for business logic. They are used for analytics and debugging. 

You likely want to have some other means of persistence, using a database or some other store, where you'd store user id and timestamp for last vote in a way that's easy to access. You might want to look sqlite or something similar, but there may be more idiomatic solutions for swift.

Comment: Save the time in `NSUserDefaults` when user votes and set a timer which is a 24-hour interval, when the timer fires, it can vote again. Considering of your app may be killed, so when the app launches, retrieve the time to check if it can vote, if not, calculate the left time and set a timer with the interval.

Comment: BTW user may kill the app and modify the system time to tomorrow, so you'd better fetch the time from your server or somewhere else on where the time is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an easy way to do it, but if you want to be certain the user is not able to vote again for 24 hours you will need to use more advanced mechanisms (store in keychain, get current date from your server instead...).

```
//Save for example vote date to user defaults
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(voteDate, forKey: "voteDate")


//Load saved date next time user wants to vote and check time passed
var canVoteNow = false
if let savedDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("voteDate") as? NSDate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let dateNow = NSDate()
    let dateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour, fromDate: savedDate, toDate: dateNow, options: nil)
    let hoursPassed = components.hour
    canVoteNow = hoursPassed >= 24
}
```